# c# WPF - Add total row in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have this DataGrid :

[image]

I would like to add at the bottom of DataGrid a Row that contain Name: Total and Price: the Sum of all price. And if is possible that this row will be frozen.
Do you have any ideas?
The simple project is in this link : [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!jpJ1zQSa!cXTI7cBxWGDeW6AFsoZ2MGQ3P6svpMFjlt0uOldVP9g)

**EDIT 1**
This is the XAML code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" />               
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and this is the ViewModel:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    public System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView Articles { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Articles = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GetArticles());
    }


    private List<Article> GetArticles()
    {
        List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();

        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name1", Price = 2.80 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name2", Price = 1.25 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name3", Price = 9.32 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name4", Price = 1.31 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name5", Price = 0.80});
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name6", Price = 2.50});
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name7", Price = 0.50 });

        return arts;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its better if you post the simplified version of your code here Instead of a link to whole project

Comment: Okay, i did it. I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more:

```
private List<Article> GetArticles()
    {
        List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();

        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name1", Price = 2.80 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name2", Price = 1.25 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name3", Price = 9.32 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name4", Price = 1.31 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name5", Price = 0.80 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name6", Price = 2.50 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name7", Price = 0.50 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Total", Price = arts.Sum(l => l.Price)});
        return arts;
    }
```

Comment: For free the last row, you create the DataGridRowStyle, add setter a ReadOnlyProperty with binding with source Name property and IValueConverter:  if Name == "Total" return true else return false

Comment: Is a good solution, but if i have a filter in datagrid the article "Total" will be lost?

Comment: Yes,  He do disable order in the column name. In the first time, add new row with totalizations, isn't a good idea. I would under the grid two textblocks with this values.

Comment: Maybe yes, Do you know how to add the textblocks under the grid and binding to the totals ?

Comment: Yes, you add a new property 'TotalPrice' in the ViewModel, and recalculate the total prices in set method of the arts property. In XAML, two texblock, one whit 'total' text and another with binding to TotalPrice Property.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding a last row to the datagrid, you can rather add a text block below your datagrid and bind it to a property which has the total price.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful.i only added a new row with a method for making the sum

```
private List<Article> GetArticles()
    {
        List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();

        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name1", Price = 2.80 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name2", Price = 1.25 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name3", Price = 9.32 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name4", Price = 1.31 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name5", Price = 0.80 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name6", Price = 2.50 });
        arts.Add(new Article { Name = "Name7", Price = 0.50 });
        arts.Add(new Article {Name = "Total", Price = GetTotal(arts)});
        return arts;
    }

    private double GetTotal(List<Article> arts)
    {
        double Total = 0;
        foreach (Article art in arts)
        {
            Total += double.Parse(art.Price.ToString());
        }
        return Total;
    }
```

Regards